Unexpected output image on inference
I'm trying to upscale image in flutter. But I'm getting unexpected result in output image. Someone please help. I tried some modification but stucked.
Model Shape:
Input Name: input, Shape: [0, 3, 0, 0]
Output Name: output, Shape: [0, 3, 0, 0]
Orginal Image
Output Image
LOG: I/flutter (  592): Image converted to normalized Float32List
I/flutter (  592): Image normalized successfully.
I/flutter (  592): Input tensor created successfully.
I/flutter (  592): Height 2880 Width 1640

Orginal Image: Height 720 Width 210

Here is the code i tried:
  Future<void> inference() async {
    if (selectedImage == null) {
      debugPrint('No image selected');
      return;
    }

    var preprocessedImage =
    NormalizeImage.imageToNormalizedFloat32List(selectedImage!);

    final shape = [1, 3, selectedImage!.height, selectedImage!.width];

    debugPrint('Image normalized successfully.');

    final inputOrt =
    OrtValueTensor.createTensorWithDataList(preprocessedImage, shape);

    final inputs = {'input': inputOrt};

    debugPrint('Input tensor created successfully.');

    final runOptions = OrtRunOptions();
    final outputs = await ortSession.runAsync(runOptions, inputs);

    inputOrt.release();
    runOptions.release();


    outputs?.forEach((element) {
      final outputValue = element?.value;
      if (outputValue is List<List<List<List<double>>>>) {
        img.Image generatedImage = generateImageFromOutput(outputValue);
        List<int> pngBytes = img.encodePng(generatedImage);
        img.Image decodedImage = img.decodeImage(Uint8List.fromList(pngBytes))!;

        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return Dialog(
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 200,
                height: 200,
                child: Image.memory(Uint8List.fromList(img.encodePng(decodedImage))),
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      } else {
        debugPrint("Output is of unknown type");
      }
      element?.release();
    });
  }
    img.Image generateImageFromOutput(List<List<List<List<double>>>> output) {
    final width = output[0][0].length;
    final height = output[0][0][0].length;
    final channels = output[0].length; // Number of channels

    debugPrint("Height: $height, Width: $width, Channels: $channels");

    // Create a new image with the specified dimensions
    img.Image imgData = img.Image(width, height);


    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
      for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        double red = output[0][y][x][0]; 
        double green = output[0][y][x][1]; 
        double blue = output[0][y][x][2]; 

        // Convert the double values to integers
        int r = (red * 255).toInt().clamp(0, 255);
        int g = (green * 255).toInt().clamp(0, 255);
        int b = (blue * 255).toInt().clamp(0, 255);

        // Set the pixel color in the image
        imgData.setPixel(x, y, img.getColor(r, g, b));

        // Debug statements
        print('Pixel at ($x, $y)');
        print('Red: $red, Green: $green, Blue: $blue');
        print('Converted RGB values: ($r, $g, $b)');
      }
    }

    return imgData;
  }

Normalize Class
class NormalizeImage {
  static Float32List imageToNormalizedFloat32List(Image image) {
    final int height = image.height;
    final int width = image.width;

    Float32List float32Image = Float32List(3 * height * width);

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        final int pixelIndex = (i * width + j) * 3;
        final int pixel = image.getPixel(j, i);

        float32Image[pixelIndex] = getRed(pixel) / 255.0;
        float32Image[pixelIndex + 1] = getGreen(pixel) / 255.0;
        float32Image[pixelIndex + 2] = getBlue(pixel) / 255.0;
      }
    }

    print("Image converted to normalized Float32List");
    return float32Image;
  }
}


